# Joda-Time Invalid format when parsing

Tags: java, date, datetime, datepicker, jodatime

Joda-Time complaining that my input is malformed but i am using the same format option:

```
'd-M-y'
```

in both the input and the Joda-Time formatter.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d-M-y");
DateTime dtFrom = formatter.parseDateTime(dateFrom);
```

The date is grabbed from a jquery datepicker field setup like this:

```
$( "#from" ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'd-M-y',
                defaultDate: null,
                changeMonth: true,
                minDate: 0,
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                    $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
                }
            });
```

The console is outputting this and you can also see the input there too, which i believe is correct

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[SearchServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet SearchServlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "26-Jan-13" is malformed at "Jan-13"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to the `SimpleDateFormat` class, a single `M` is used to parse a numeric month value. You can use `MMM` to parse text-based months:

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d-MMM-y");
```

From [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html):

> Month: 3 or over, use text, otherwise use number.